# Converting pandas dataframe to ordered list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
          min       max
Loc
0    0.000331  0.000000
4    0.000330  0.000000
9    0.000000  0.000351
11   0.000342  0.000000
19   0.000000  0.000368
25   0.000000  0.000381
31   0.000361  0.000000
32   0.000361  0.000000
38   0.000000  0.000378
42   0.000367  0.000000
46   0.000000  0.000375
49   0.000373  0.000000
```

I need to convert it to a list of lists where every sublist is `Loc` and `min/max`, so it would become this: `[[0, 0.000331], [0, 0.000000], [4, 0.000330], [4, 0.000000], [9, 0.000000], [9, 0.000351], [11, 0.000342], [0, 0.000000] ...]`

The problem is that i don't know how to do it. I know how to convert it to a simple list or list of lists using a simple `.stack().tolist()` but the problem, in this case, is that i need every sublist to be `[Loc, min]` and then `[Loc, max]` and, most important thing, they need to be ordered in the same way of the dataframe.

Is there a clean way to do this using pandas built-in functions or am i going to have to loop through the dataframe?

Comment: just curious, why `min > max` at `Loc 0`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html) practicing the examples.

Comment: maybe `list(df.stack().to_frame("vals").itertuples(name=None))` if you don't mind tuples

Comment: @QuangHoang It's not bigger, it's basically that i'm using a function that finds local minima and maxima for a given interval. When there is 0, it means that there wasn't a local maxima for that interval (an interval is 3 rows), i should have used a simple N/A

Comment: @Manakin Thank you a lot, the problem is that i'll get something like ((3, 'min'), 0.0003301), while i need simply (3, 0.000301)

Comment: you can just drop the index before - `list(df.stack().reset_index(1, drop=True).to_frame("vals").itertuples(name=None))`

Comment: `[[l, m] for l, *M in df.itertuples() for m in M]`

Comment: for maximum efficiency, use `name=None` in the call to `itertuples`... `[[l, m] for l, *M in df.itertuples(name=None) for m in M]`

Comment: Thank you a lot everyone! I managed to do it! Thanks for the help!